# Reappear fixed position element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a `fixed` positioned element. CSS is  like below

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
```

[image]

If I make the position `static`, element disappears from screen. How can I reappear the element ?

Comment: please add html also. and what do you mean by reappear the element?

Comment: Thanks @XenioGracias. HTML is too big. Should I include screen shot ? I would like to keep the element stay in screen with `static` position. Thanks.

Comment: you don't want that element to be fixed?. Don't add the full HTML. add only which you want us to check

Comment: since `position: static` is default behavior, setting it explicitly is like deleting `position: fixed`, effectively.

Comment: Thanks @XenioGracias for your reply. Yes, I don't want that element to be fixed. I added a screenshot. May be that is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DaemonPainter. What can I do in this regard ? Thanks.

Comment: then remove `position:fixed` property from `css`

Comment: @XenioGracias, If I do that then the element disappear from the screen. Thanks.

Comment: you can have a look at my answer, and you should explain how you'd like the final element to look like. Try adding relevant HTML and a mockup of desired output.

Comment: please add that header div html code

Comment: @DaemonPainter, I made a comment in your `Answer`. Thanks.

Comment: according to the screenshot, z-index is being override by something, most likely some call elsewhere in your page.

Comment: @DaemonPainter, How can I find that `z-index` which occur this disappearing ? Thanks.

Comment: start from the `mm-slideout` class and the `header` selector, than move your way back.

Answer (score 1):

`position: static` is incompatible with relative positioning (`top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `z-index`), and will override those settings. Your element is going to follow the normal page flow.

`position: relative` is just like static, but will retain those settings. Note that position will be relative to current page flow.

Comment: Thanks @Daemon Painter. Actually the element is a `Sticky` header. I don't need the stickiness. I would like to make it static. Even I don't need `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `z-index` etc. Thanks.

Comment: why do you want it to be statics so bad? As already pointed out, `position: static` is equivalent to remove the `position:` statement from your styling at all... Please, provide a minimum working example for us to improve the answers

Comment: `position: static` and `position:` both are giving me same result that disappearing the element. I mentioned earlier `I don't need the stickiness`. But the element will stay there at it's position. Thanks

Comment: fine, but there is no apparent stickiness in the code you provided... Not to me, at least. I would expect `position: sticky`, instead of `position: fixed` in such case. This looks like a [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).